# SQL - How to retrieve the correct number

Tags: sql, database

I have written a personal pseudocode to help others understand what I am trying to achieve. I am a beginner in SQL but I know all the basics, just not experienced enough with the possiblilities.

I tried using SELECT CASE but it doesn't achieve what I need.

Here is my sample data

```
CREATE TABLE Records
    ([ColA] INTEGER, [ColB] INTEGER, [ColTotal] INTEGER)
;

INSERT INTO Records
    ([ColA], [ColB] )
VALUES
    ('3', '4'),
    ('4', '2’),
    ('1', '2'),
    ('3', '5'),
    ('3', '1'),
    ('2', '2')
;
```

Here is my PSEUDOCODE   (I found out after accepted answer that my logic in the psuedo was incorrect too.  This has been fixed)

```
SELECT COL A, COL B, COL TOTAL
IF COL A  >= COLB THEN
ADD COLB value to COL TOTAL
ELSE
USE Value from COLA and add to total
END IF
```

Here is my SQL

```
SELECT SUM(ColTotal)
FROM t
WHERE ColA >= ColB
```

Comment: Sample data is better than pseudo code.  Tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select sum(case when a < b then a else b end) as total
from t;
```

Many databases support the `least()` function, which makes this simpler:

```
select sum(least(a, b)) as total
from t;
```

Comment: thank you very much, almost perfect answer.     select sum(case when a >= b then b else a end) as total
from t;   I just needed to swap the logic around in your SQL to get my desired answer. I will approve this as accepted answer as it answered my question. thanks again for sharing your professional knowledge and experience on this matter.  It has taken me 6 hours to work with what I have.  w3school and dummy SQL server which I am reading lots of SQL statements on internet that didn't apply to me.